# Deploying stored procedures with CosmosDb

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, devops

In an asp.net core application in Azure, I am using some stored procedures in a CosmosDB database.

I know how to create these stored procedures with C# code. But, I do not know when to deploy them (in my web app, by powershell, in a separate command line application...)

Answer (score 0):

When bootstrapping your DocumentClient, upsert your stored procedures for unpartitioned collections to simplify deployment. For partitioned collections, you have to delete/create the stored procedures - which can be problematic if you are upgrading your system in flight.

Comment: Is there an example of this somewhere?